# angular api calls in loops / functions in specific order

Tags: angularjs

I've lost count of how many times I've tried to make this work.  I just don't get it.

Let's pretend I have the following API calls:

api/customer(cust)

api/orders(orderid)

api/products(productid)

api/related(relatedid)

When all is said and done, I need a single object that contains all the data as arrays and sub arrays (will explain below).

I need to start by doing an api call to api/customer.  The return is going to be that customer's previous orders as an array of objects.  Let's pretend they made three orders.

Inside each object is various key : value pairs, including one called "products" which itself is an array of productid numbers.

Now I must loop through all the product id numbers and with each one, call:

api/products(productid)

This also will return an array which must be looped through to find each product's "relatedid" value.

Then inside the above loop I must once again contact the API with:

api/related(relatedid)

Which then returns all the products related to each product in each order of each customer.

When all is said and done a single customer might have three orders, and each order could have 5 products and each product could have 10 related products.

How do you code something like this, making sure that each API call from the top down completes before continuing on?  How do you do that inside multiple loops?

When all is said and done I'm hoping for something like this:

```
{
customerid: 10
previousOrderids: {10, 11, 12}  
orderedProducts: {10: {101, 102, 103, 104}, 11:{201, 202, 203, 204}, 12:{301, 302}
relatedProducts: {101: {5, 6, 7}, 102: {7,8,9} } (etc...)
}
```

and so on.  I've left the above short for brevity, but i'm hoping it's obvious I am trying to build a "tree" of data where I start with a single API call with static data (the customer's id) and then from there, make calls using what is in the API responses.

I know about defered promises, $q.all, .then, etc etc.  But everything I try just gets me going around in circles.  Forget about even making nice compact functions to handle each bit.  I understand the basics, but I have never seen an actual real world example of how to assemble something complicated.

Can someone help me understand how to handle multiple asynchronous actions where each one depends on the results of the one before it?  And especially where multiple async actions must be called in various loop(s) and completed before moving on?

I've done things like this in server side languages like PHP, but those are easy when the code won't advance until the current action is done.

I'd post some of the code I've tried, but it's a total joke.

Thank you.

Comment: using `promises`. you can check this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
if restful you can use `$resource` as well.

Comment: Post your code as you said, maybe it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `promises`
Consider calling first api

```
someService.getCustomer().then(response => {
     // call next api
     someService.getOrders().then(resp =>{
              // call next api and so on
     });
});
```

P.S: I am assuming you have angular code.

Comment: I've seen all that.  It doesn't help with something complicated like this, where there are API lookups inside loops and you must wait for each loop to finish before moving on.

Comment: you would have to wait till you know what you are looking for. not sure how you can skip that. iff you have all the necessary data in one go.

Comment: Also, doing it that way would (even if it worked) end up with a massive set of nested .then's.  At least four of them, and don't forget there will be loops inside most of them.  I believe that qualifies as anti-pattern.

I need to figure out how to do it where each step is its own function.  Each one gets called in order, returns its data and only then does the next function get called.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experienced with Angular, and I might have made some mistakes, but if this was my project I would try the following way:

Create your module

```
var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);
```

Create a service called aggregator

```
app.factory('aggregator', ['$q', function($q) {
    var aggregator = {};

    // object properties and method here

    return aggregator;
]};
```

It should be able to do the following operations:

```
aggregator.getCustomer = function(customerID) {
    // this is where you would implement calls to your api
    // however, as api calls take long, it is a good place to use
    // a promise because you can sort of synchronize asynchronous functions this way
    // before returning the promise, you need to define what happens
    // when you receive some response
    // implementation further down the answer
};

aggregator.getCustomerPreviousOrders = function(customerID) {
    // implementation to follow
};

aggregator.getOrderedProducts = function(orderIDsArray) {
    // implementation to follow
};

aggregator.getRelated = function(productID) {
    // implementation to follow
};
```

Each of these methods should return a promise, and it works in pretty much the same way, regardless of what part of api you're calling.

For example, getting a customer could be done like this:

```
aggregator.getCustomer = function(customerID) {
    // make sure you have injected $q

    // first you create an object that will be able to:
    // 1. promise your customer data to another object
    // 2. call api
    // 3. if result returned from api call is positive, it passes the results to the object it made the promise to
    // 4. if result is negative, it rejects the promise it made before,
    // thus, still providing some answer
    // With $q, you create this object by calling $q.defer()
    var result = $q.defer();

    // Then you make your api call
    $http({
               method: 'GET'
              ,url:    'api/customer'
              ,params: { id: customerID }
         }).then(function callbackSuccess(response) {

             result.resolve(response); // in success callback you resolve and include the response in promise resolution. When this happens, you will be able to proceed to the next api call

         }, function callbackError(error) {

             result.reject(error) // in error callback you reject and include the error in promise rejection. When this happens you will stop your chain of api calls and get an error which you can handle nicely

         });



    // Then, as you will reach the end of this function before you receive api response, you must return a promise, so that the object that called this getCustomer function can hold on to something at least
    return result.promise;

}
```

Then you define all the other functions using the same principle, and then you can chain these api calls in your controller, like this:

```
app.controller('someController', ['$scope', 'aggregator', function($scope, aggregator) {

    $scope.onCustomerSelected = function(id) {
        $scope.customerID = id;
    }

    $scope.loadData = function() {
        // in here you can chain your aggregator functions
        aggregator.getCustomer($scope.customerID) // wherever your customerID comes from
        .then(aggregator.getCustomerPreviousOrders(response))
        .then(aggregator.getOrderedProducts(response))
        .then(aggregator.getRelated(response))
        .then(function(response) {
            // here you finally handle your response with all the collected data
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
            // here you handle any errors that come up in the chain of api calls
            // whichever call ends up with an error will be handled by this handler and that is one elegant way to handle errors
        });
    }

    $scope.loadData();
}]);
```

**EDIT** - Browsing around I found more options [here](https://medium.com/@will_gottchalk/write-modern-asynchronous-javascript-using-promises-generators-and-coroutines-5fa9fe62cf74#.ldasbcflz). Have a look, I hope it will help.